# Angular 2 - Rerun constructor once revisit the page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I would like to know how can I refresh data once revisit the Page.

Here is my github project for example: https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/tree/Medicine-module-complete-add/edit/del/view/list

you can see there is A page called `Medicine` and there is an option to remove/edit `Medicine's` value (slide left).
When you have succsfully edited the data and return the Page `Medicine` the data is still the same because the variable is not reset.

If I want to view the current state of the data i have to refresh the page, that makes the constructor rerun.

There is a way/idea that can I do it?

Thanks A Head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the angular2/ionic2 life cycle hooks.
A constructor is executed when the class is created but has no relation to the actual view.

For ionic2 use:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hi');
}
```

For angular2 use:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    console.log('Hi'); 
}
```

You can look the whole list here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Observables and poll the data every 2 seconds on the service.
the observable will update every time the data is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have find a function that called every time there is enter to the page:

```
   ionViewWillEnter(){
       // your code goes here.
   }
```

Thanks!